# Why did I get "permission denied when opening output file" when I used clock_t to time a program in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program in which I have a function and I am hoping to time it. Currently, I considered `clock_t` in the `ctime` module to be useful, but when I entered the code for timing, I got (I used Dev-C++ to edit) "**permission denied**". Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
// Initialization
const int maxN = 99999;
int tokens[maxN] = {}; // All the tokens at mission 1
bool use[maxN] = {}; // Status of the tokens (used or not used)
int bag[maxN]; // Bag to put the tokens into
using namespace std;

int ansIdx = 1; // Answer number

char menu() {
    // Print menu
    cout << "0: terminate\n";
    cout << "1: mission 1 - permutations from 1 ~ N\n";
    cout << "2: mission 2 - permutations from input\n";
    // Ask for input
    cout << "Please input a choice (0 ~ 2): ";
    char choice;
    cin >> choice;
    // Valid command?
    if (choice >= '0' and choice <= '2') {
        return choice;
    }
    return '\0';
}

int permutations(int depth, int n, int l) {
    if (depth == n) {
        // Arranged all elements, so cout each of the elements.
        cout << "[" << ansIdx << "] ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << bag[i] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
        ansIdx++;
        return l;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Else, for each UNUSED element at this layer:
        if (use[i] == 0) {
            // Put it into bag[i].
            bag[depth] = tokens[i];
            // Set the status of it used.
            use[i] = 1;
            // Call recursion.
            permutations(depth + 1, n, l+1);
            // Backtrack.
            use[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Print menu.
    cout << "PERMUTATION GENERATOR\n";
    char executionMode;
    while (executionMode != '0') {
        executionMode = menu();
        while (executionMode == '\0') {
            executionMode = menu();
        }
        int layers;
        clock_t start;
        double ms;
        switch (executionMode) {
            case '1':
                cout << "Enter N: ";
                int N;
                cin >> N;
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    tokens[i] = i + 1;
                }
                start = clock();
                layers = permutations(0, N, 0);
                ms = ((double)(clock() - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                cout << "L = " << layers << "\n";
                cout << "Mission 1: " << ansIdx - 1 << " permutations\n";
                cout << "Used: " << ms << "ms\n";
                ansIdx = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                int M = 0;
                while (M < 2 or M > 9) {
                    cout << "Enter length of input (2 ~ 9): ";
                    cin >> M;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                    cout << "Enter a number: ";
                    cin >> tokens[i];
                }
                start = clock();
                layers = permutations(0, M, 0);
                ms = ((double)(clock() - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                cout << "L = " << layers << "\n";
                cout << "Mission 2: " << ansIdx - 1 << " permutations\n";
                cout << "Used: " << ms << "ms";
                ansIdx = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The shown code compiles and runs without errors, at least insofar as showing the main menu. It has some other, obvious bugs, but I am unable to reproduce anything that resembles a "permission denied" error. Unable to reproduce. As far as suggestions go, can you review stackoverflow.com's directions for [ask] questions?

Comment: "Permission Denied" sounds like the execution tried to access a function not allowed on your system. Please edit your question and list the OS you are running this on as well as what compiler and flags you used. Nothing obvious in the code `ctime() and `clock_t` are common system calls and types.

Comment: Also, if the program compiles,  provide the input arguments you used. Could be something like accessing an element in an array out of bounds but that doesn't produce "Permission Denied" on anything I've run across.

Comment: I ran the code again and discovered that the program suddenly compiles. Is this due to Dev C++'s stability?

Comment: VS2019 running code successfully. Getting suggestion about 'clock() - start' ... C26451 coversion might overflow

Comment: Oops. Discovered something. Dev-C++ seems to raise an "Permission denied" error when you already opened a execution file.